# Outlook VSTO: Convert Redemption.RDOFolder to Outlook.MAPIFolder

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I am able to get a corresponding RDOFolder from Outlook.MAPIFolder using

```
RDOFolder f = rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(outlookMapiFolder)
```

rdoSession is initialised with current Outlook session.

How to convert a RDOFolder back to Outlook.MAPIFolder for further processing?

Comment: I've fixed the problem by reducing the scope of the RDO Objects in my program. Nevertheless i'm interessted, if there is a supported way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `Namespace.GetFolderFromID(f.EntryID)`.